# How do I get OS X version as root?

Tags: macos

As a normal user I can get the version of OS X with the command

```
$ defaults read loginwindow SystemVersionStampAsString
```

However, if I run the command as root it fails:

```
$ sudo defaults read loginwindow SystemVersionStampAsString
2012-08-22 18:51:06.941 defaults[427:1707] 
The domain/default pair of (loginwindow, SystemVersionStampAsString) does not exist
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a command line tool called 'sw_vers':

```
$ sw_vers
```

It should print out the version information; for example:

```
ProductName:    OS X
ProductVersion: 10.3
BuildVersion:   7A100
```

Comment: Thanks, the command `sw_vers | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":[ \t]*" } /ProductVersion/ { print $2 }'` prints only the version string.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can gather, defaults belong to "domains", and running the defaults command for a superuser, means running the command defaults in a subshell, this subshell has no domain "loginwindow", hence the error. Only the shell running directly in the terminal application has the terminal application as domain "loginwindow", no subshell with for another user will have it though.

Try

```
  sudo defaults domains
```

to get a list of available domains for the superuser.